# Evaluate probability given moment generating function

Tags: probability, statistics

> The mgf of $X$ is given by $M(t) = 0.4 + 0.3e^t + 0.2e^{2t} + 0.1e^{3t}$, what is $P(X \le 1)$?

I know that $M(t) = E[e^{tX}]$

but I am unable to see the relation between $t, X$

Answer (score 0):

Writing out the definition of the MGF, we see that
$$ E[e^{tX}] = \sum_{n} P(X=n) e^{tn}. $$
Therefore $P(X=n)$ is the coefficient of $e^{tn}$. So you can read off
$$ P(X=0) = 0.4, \qquad P(X=1) = 0.3, \qquad P(X=2) = 0.2, \qquad P(X=3) = 0.1 $$
and from there it's easy.